# Is orlah forbidden from benefit or just from eating?

Tags: halacha, orla-revai

What is the extent of the prohibition of *orlah*?  Is it just eating that is prohibited (*issur achila*), as is written ([Vayikira 19:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), or is benefiting from *orlah* also prohibited (*issur hana'ah*)?

Answer (score 5):

*Orlah* (fruit from trees planted within 3 years) is forbidden for all benefit, see e.g., Mishne Torah [Maachalot Assurot 10:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968266/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-10.htm)

> Whenever anyone plants a fruit tree, it is forbidden **to partake of
>   or benefit from all of the fruit the tree produces for three years**
>   after being planted

For details see e.g., [here](https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/daily-living/32-The-Jewish-Garden.html) from aish. Note this applies both in and outside Israel.